# static assert for const variables?

Tags: c++, static-assert

Static asserts are very convenient for checking things in compile time. A simple static assert idiom looks like this:

```
template<bool> struct StaticAssert;
template<> struct StaticAssert<true> {};

#define STATIC_ASSERT(condition) do { StaticAssert<(condition)>(); } while(0)
```

This is good for stuff like

```
STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(float) == 4)
```

and:

```
#define THIS_LIMIT (1000)
...
STATIC_ASSERT(THIS_LIMIT > OTHER_LIMIT);
```

But using `#define` is not the "C++" way of defining constants. C++ would have you use an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
    const int THIS_LIMIT = 1000;
}
```

or even:

```
static const int THIS_LIMIT = 1000;
```

The trouble with this is that with a `const int` you can't use `STATIC_ASSERT()` and you must resort to a run-time check which is silly.

Is there a way to properly solve this in current C++?
I think I've read C++0x has some facility to do this...

---

**EDIT**

Ok so this

```
static const int THIS_LIMIT = 1000;
...
STATIC_ASSERT(THIS_LIMIT > 0);
```

compiles fine
But this:

```
static const float THIS_LIMIT = 1000.0f;
...
STATIC_ASSERT(THIS_LIMIT > 0.0f);
```

does not.
(in Visual Studio 2008)

How come?

Comment: Why are you using NIH static assert, instead of BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html

Comment: I can't use boost (yet) for some silly corporate reason

Comment: What makes you think you can't use integral constants in this case? The above should work just fine.

Comment: Floating-point values have a few static restrictions over integral ones. Note, for example, that you cannot pass them as template arguments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why, you can still static assert with const int:

```
#define static_assert(e) extern char (*ct_assert(void)) [sizeof(char[1 - 2*!(e)])]
static_assert( THIS_LIMIT > OTHER_LIMIT )
```

Also, [use boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html)!

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( THIS_LIMIT > OTHER_LIMIT )
```

... you'll get a **lot** nicer error messages...

Comment: Well, there's a lesson for me. don't say something isn't possible before trying it...

Comment: @shoosh: You original code should compile fine. See [my reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902917/2903013#2903013).

Comment: @Georg, I just posted the one I use in lack of boost -- it's advantage is that it doesn't have to be in function scope. As for error readability -- depends on the compiler.

Comment: @sbi: Ah, no problem. @Kornel: Maybe its only me, but i read it as *"use this instead, otherwise it won't work"*, you don't mention that the OPs original approach already worked.

Answer (score 5):

`static_assert` is a compiler feature in C++0x so as long as you've got a relatively up-to-date compiler you can use that.  Watch out for doing `#define static_assert(x) ...`, because it's a real keyword in C++0x so you'd be permanently hiding the compiler feature.  Also, C++0x `static_assert` takes two parameters (eg. `static_assert(sizeof(int) == 4, "Expecting int to be 4 bytes")`), so you could cause yourself problems trying to switch in future if you use that #define.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're *really* asking why the following is the case (and I can confirm that in both GCC 4.3.4 and Visual C++ 2008 Express):

```
template<bool> struct StaticAssert;
template<> struct StaticAssert<true> {};

#define STATIC_ASSERT(condition) do { StaticAssert<(condition)>(); } while(0)


static const int   AN_INT  = 1000;
static const float A_FLOAT = 1000.0f;

int main()
{
   STATIC_ASSERT(AN_INT > 0);     // OK
   STATIC_ASSERT(A_FLOAT > 0.0f); // Error: A_FLOAT may not appear in a constant expression
}
```

There are number of restrictions on using floating-point values statically. Note, for example, that you cannot pass them as template arguments. That is because:

> `[C++11: 5.19/2]:` **A *conditional-expression* is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following as a potentially evaluated subexpression** (3.2), but subexpressions of logical AND (5.14), logical OR (5.15), and conditional (5.16) operations that are not evaluated are not considered [ *Note:* An overloaded operator invokes a
>   function. *—end note* ]**:**
>
> - [..]
> - **an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) unless it is applied to**
>
>   - **a glvalue of integral or enumeration type** that refers to a non-volatile const object with a preceding initialization, initialized with a constant expression, or
>   - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr, or that refers to a sub-object of such an object, or
>   - a glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile temporary object whose lifetime has not ended, initialized with a constant expression;
> - [..]

(i.e. only integral and enumeration types are allowed; no floating-point types.)

As for the *reason* for this rule, I'm not entirely sure, but the following sort of rationale may well have something to do with it:

> `[C++11: 5.19/4]:` [..] Since this International Standard imposes no restrictions on the
>   accuracy of floating-point operations, **it is unspecified whether the evaluation of a floating-point expression during translation yields the same result as the evaluation of the same expression** (or the same operations on the same values) **during program execution**. [..]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're confusing C++'s behavior with C, where `const int` does not represent a true compile-time constant.  Or perhaps your C++ compiler is broken.  If it's truly the latter, use `enum` instead.

Comment: you got +1, i got -1 for the same solution =/

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: To be fair, my answer provides mores explanation than yours, and using `enum` should *not* be necessary in C++ for this case.

Comment: @ViktorSehr: This place is not about chucking out "solutions" in snippets of code like they were pieces of meat; it's about writing _answers_ to explain, teach and inform. Often, good answers include code illustrations, but that does _not_ mean that an answer which consists _solely_ of code is a good one. Indeed, it's rare that that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
namespace {
    const int THIS_LIMIT = 1000;
}

template<bool> struct StaticAssert;
template<> struct StaticAssert<true> {};

#define STATIC_ASSERT(condition) do { StaticAssert<(condition)>(); } while(0)

int main()
{
    STATIC_ASSERT(THIS_LIMIT > 5);

    return (0);
}
```

compiles fine with VC and Comeau.

Answer (score 0):

`enum{THIS_LIMIT = 1000};`

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but this is hardly an answer to the given question. It's a valid workaround, and it's valid code, but you provided zero description, zero explanation and zero analysis of (a) what it does, (b) how it differs from the OP's code and (c) why it should be used (and, in fact, it _doesn't_ need to be). Consequently it comes across as a little lazy, and that's probably why it was downvoted. In fact, come to think of it, I'm going to downvote it too for that reason. Sorry.